# What is the unique map for the equalizer in set?

Tags: category-theory

What is the unique map for the equalizer in set?

If $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$ and $e : \{x \in X :f(x) = g(x) \} \rightarrow X$
and if $h : D \rightarrow X$ such that $fh=gh$, what exactly is the notation for the unique map $h' : D \rightarrow \{x \in X : f(x) = g(x)\}$ such that $e \circ h' = h$?

It looks it would just be $h' = h$ since every $h(d) \in \{x \in X : f(x) = g(x)\}$, but I'm not entirely sure this is correct.

Comment: $h'=h$ is a wrong expression, because they have different codomains, but their behaviour is really the same on the elements of the set (you might want to say that $h'(x):=h(x)$ for all $x$ in $D$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $e$ is just the inclusion of the subset $E = \{ x \in X \mid f(x) = g(x) \} \subseteq X$ into $X$. The function $h'$ is then the corestriction of $h : D \to X$ to $E$, i.e. it's the function $h' : D \to E$ defined by $h'(d)=h(d)$ for all $d \in D$. Note that this is well-defined precisely because $E$ is (a subset of) the equaliser of $f$ and $g$.

It is slightly misleading to say $h'=h$, since although $h'(d)=h(d)$ for all $d \in D$, the functions $h$ and $h'$ have different codomains.